# Nginx 404 on static html file

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed nginx on ubuntu 18.04 but I am not able to serve plain html files as everything just gives me a 404 error.

Here is my nginx.conf (not modified):

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My default file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /andreas/www;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html app.js;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Nginx access log shows the following:

```
"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that the "root" was set to the incorrect folder, after it was correctly updated everything works.